# How to find the number of articles in a string by using c?

Tags: c

A string S is passed as the input. The program must print the number of articles in S.

I have no idea about this problem. Help me to find a solution to this problem.

Input:
I went to a movie yesterday along with an old man.

Output:
2

There are two articles in the string.

Comment: [article?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar))

Comment: First of all, you need to know what an article is. Say, you can have a hardcoded array of what you'd classify as an article.

Comment: and first you have to extract the words from your input to compare each with your list of articles

Comment: First you need to figure out what an 'article' is (hint it is a class of words much like noun or verb), then figure out how to split a sentence into words, i.e. "I went to a movie yesterday along with an old man" into "I", "went", "to", "a", "movie", "yesterday", "along", "with", "an", "old", "man".  Then how to count the number of articles.  Although the sentence "the cat ran into the house" has a single article that appears twice so you need to figure out if you should report one article or the number of occurrences of that article.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking how to edit a file to generate source code?  Are you asking about how to compile a program?  Are you asking how to run it?  Are you asking how to read data?  Are you asking how to parse data?  Are you asking how to increment a variable?  Are you asking how to recognize an article?  Are you asking how to tokenize the input?  So many possible variations.  Be specific.

Comment: Start by writing the "hello world" program. Then write a program which prints the sentence you gave as input. Break the problem into small steps and you will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where your problem is, so I hope that this could help you

You can enter a text witch scanf. To split this string use strtok and for the comperison strcmp.
Also look:
https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strtok

https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strcmp

so here is how it can look like:

```c
int main()
{

    char arr[MAX];
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);
    int count = 0;
    char *token = strtok(arr, " ");
    while(token)
    {
        if(strcmp(token, "an") == 0|| strcmp(token, "a") == 0 || strcmp(token, "the") == 0)
            count++;
        if(strcmp(token, "An") == 0|| strcmp(token, "A") == 0 || strcmp(token, "The") == 0)
            count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("Output: %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

you could make an char array for the articles and than interate it. And don't foget to inlcude the librarys for this ;)